# is it possible to run wine 32-bits on a docker container?

Tags: linux, docker, wine

I have tried different versions of wine 32-bits on different versions of Ubuntu or/and Debian docker containers but I got this error or similar

```
/usr/bin/wine32: 1: /usr/bin/wine32: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

I have tried other people wine containers with a similar result, so now I'm wondering is it even possible to run wine 32-bits on a docker container?

Comment: Please don't include "thanks" or similar. See here for more info: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: Stack Overflow is for questions relating to software development. This question would probably be more appropriate on https://superuser.com/.